# Docker container (aspnet:5.0-alpine3.13) unable to download a file using curl

Tags: docker, dockerfile

When I do following command using `docker run` the file downloads fine:

```
$ docker run mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/aspnet:5.0-alpine3.13 apk add curl \
&& echo "start" \
&& curl -L --output file-example_PDF_1MB.pdf https://file-examples-com.github.io/uploads/2017/10/file-example_PDF_1MB.pdf && echo "done"
```

The file downloads fine, however when I try to download it in the container by the following `Dockerfile`:

```
FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/aspnet:5.0-alpine3.13 AS runtime
    
RUN apk add curl \
&& curl -L --output file-example_PDF_1MB.pdf https://file-examples-com.github.io/uploads/2017/10/file-example_PDF_1MB.pdf
```

The `curl` command fails with the following error message:

```
docker build -t testsem .
    
curl: (6) Could not resolve host: file-examples-com.github.io
```

The linux docker image is used (aspnet:5.0-alpine3.13) host OS is Windows 10 Pro.

I've tried to disable firewall on the host machine - no difference, same error message.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A solution that worked for me was to add custom DNSs to docker configuration file `/etc/docker/daemon.json` like follow:

```json
{
    "dns": [
        "1.1.1.1",
        "8.8.8.8"
     ]
}
```

I hope it may help you.

Regards.